# URLs diferentes acessando o mesmo projeto mas com configurações diferentes

Tags: htaccess, sistema-de-arquivos, programação-estruturada

Tenho um sistema web. E diversas empresas usam esse sistema, mas cada uma com suas configurações específicas. Atualmente eu duplico o conteúdo dos arquivos e crio uma nova pasta com eles. Mas fica complicado de dar manutenção em todos. Queria colocar o sistema em uma única pasta do meu servidor e criar urls específicas para cada empresa mas utilizando o mesmos arquivos no servidor. Por exemplo, teria um /cliente-a, em que o cliente acessaria o projeto com configurações específicas e outro /cliente-b em que outras configurações seriam acessadas porém utilizando os mesmos arquivos no servidor. É possível fazer algo assim? Qual o passo-a-passo? Lembrando que o cliente acessaria essa url específica para todo o projeto, porém não existiriam pastas físicas /cliente-a e cliente-b, sería só pra ele ter um domínio especifico.